# GitHub にプッシュしようとすると "SSL_connect: Connection was reset in connection to github.com:443" エラーが発生する

Tags: git, github

Githubのリポジトリをクローンし、それをwindows10環境下のgitをインストールしたVisual Studio Codeで内容を書き換えコミットし、それをGitHubにプッシュしようとしたところ、以下のエラーが表示されました。
また、プッシュと同様にプルも同じエラー文が表示されました。

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/XXX/XXXXX.git/': OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection was reset in connection to github.com:443
```

二か月前まではVSCode内でプル/プッシュ共にできたのですが、二か月ぶりに行おうとしたところ、エラー文が表示されるようになりました。

エラー文で検索したところ、下記を打ち込めばいいと書かれているので試したのですが、解決しませんでした。

```
git config --global --unset-all remote.origin.proxy
```

正常にプッシュするにはどうすればよいでしょうか？
素人程度の知識しかないので情報が不足していたらすみません。

Comment: 参考までに、Git のバージョンは確認できますか？

Comment: 未解決で終了したようですがマルチポストらしきもの。[Visual Studio Code を用いてGithubのレポジトリにプッシュしようとしたところ、以下のエラーが表示されました。](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q12267354787)

Comment: 解決しておらずGitHubでもない(少しはGitに関係している)けれどこんな記事があります。[fatal: unable to access 'https://dev.azure.com/xxx': OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection was reset in connection to dev.azure.com:443](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67230241/9014308) いろんな回答があって、何か参考になるかも。

Comment: Gitのバージョンを調べたところ、2.37.3でした。また、以前にYahoo知恵袋の方で同様の質問を行いましたが、2週間以上回答が得られないまま質問期間が過ぎたためこちらの方で質問いたしました。

Comment: リンクを掲載してくださりありがとうございます。リンク先でも同じエラーが発生しているようですが、そちらはIPv6を使用していることが原因のようですね。私はIPv4を使用しているにも関わらず同様のエラーが発生する状況です。また、ネットワーク設定をパブリックからプライベートに変更する手段も試しましたが、解決しませんでした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yahoo知恵袋で質問したところ、問題が解決したためこちらにも解決方法を記載いたします。

参考URL: https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q14269174659

私はプル/プッシュ先としてhttpsで指定したURLを使っていました。
理由は、以前はSSHを使うとエラーが発生していたからです。
今回、httpsのURLではなくSSHの方に変更したところ、正常にプル/プッシュできるようになりました。